# My two layer neural network model doesn't converge

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I am training a two layer neural network. I waited for 15000 epochs, still model doesn't converge.

```
ans = []
for i in range(1000):
    x1,y1 = random.uniform(-3,3),random.uniform(-3,3)
    if x1*x1 + y1 * y1 < 1:
        ans.append([x1,y1,0])
    elif x1*x1 + y1 * y1 >= 2 and x1*x1 + y1 * y1 <=8:
        ans.append([x1,y1,1])

data = pd.DataFrame(ans)
print(data.shape)
X = np.array(data[[0,1]])
y = np.array(data[2])
```

I am generating random points generating data. the data looks like something like this.
[image]

```
weights_layer1 = np.random.normal(scale=1 / 10**.5, size=(2,20))
bias1 = np.zeros((1,20))
bias2 = np.zeros((1,1))
weights_layer2 = np.random.normal(scale=1 / 10**.5, size=(20,1))
for e in range(15000):
    for x,y1 in zip(X,y):
         x = x.reshape(1,2)
         layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(x,weights_layer1)+bias1)
         layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1,weights_layer2)+bias2)
        
        dk = (y1-layer2)*layer2*(1-layer2)
        dw2 = learnrate * dk * layer1.T
        dw2 =dw2.reshape(weights_layer2.shape)
   # print(dw2.shape)
    
    
        weights_layer2 += dw2
   # bias2 += dk * learnrate
    
        dj = weights_layer2.T* layer1*(1-layer1)*dk
        dw1 = learnrate * np.dot(x.T,dj)
```

I am calculating loss in this manner.

```
loss = 0
for x,y1 in zip(X,y):
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(x,weights_layer1))
    layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1,weights_layer2))
    loss += (layer2 - y1)**2
    
    
print(loss)
```

cant find what is going wrong,can you see anything? Thanks. I trained the same with pytorch it is converging fine.

the final model looks like this on trained data. but on test data it is worse.
[image]

Comment: There is no way anyone can help with this unless you also share the data and the full code.

Comment: x is just set of points which are inside and outside a circle, it has to detect if the point is inside or outside

Comment: I am generating random inputs and checking accuracy on random points.

Comment: Please take a look at the guidelines for asking a question. If you expect others to do work just to be able to reproduce your issue, they are simply going to move on to the next question. You need to help us help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. When asking a quesiton, please post the full question, including any code you have for generating data etc.

Comment: added  code to generate input.

Comment: that's all the code needed to train this network.including data.

Comment: first you should change -3, 3 data range to -1, 1 so its normalized and easier to learn from. And are you sure you implemented backprob correctly? I dont see a MSE or sigmoid derivitive

Comment: sigmoid derivative is layer2*(1-layer2). let me try -1 and 1.

Comment: tried same with pytorch it is working fine. didn't need to change it to -1 and 1

Comment: found the issue. this network needs biases otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of trying out, I found the problem. This network doesn't converge without biases. Used biases it converged in 5000 epochs.